# How to manually reconnect Blazor server App?

Tags: signalr, blazor-server-side

I have customized Blazor Server SignalR settings like show below here.
What are my options to reconnect, without forcing reload of page ?

```
 <button  id="refreshButton" class="btn btn-info ms-1" style="display:none" onclick="Reconnect()">Refresh Page</button>


<script src="_framework/blazor.server.js" autostart="false"></script>

<script>
        function Reconnect()
        {
           
           console.log("attempting to reconnect");

           window.location.reload(true); //this works but looking for better option
        
             
        }
      window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function () {
          Blazor.defaultReconnectionHandler._reconnectionDisplay = document.getElementById("refreshButton");
      });
       window.addEventListener('pagehide', () => {
          Blazor.disconnect();
        
        });
     
        Blazor.start({
      
        reconnectionHandler: {
            onConnectionDown: (options, error) => { 
                document.getElementById("refreshButton").style="";
                console.error("Connection is down " + error)
            } ,
            onConnectionUp: () =>  {
            console.log("Up, up, and away!")
                document.getElementById("refreshButton").style="display:none";
            }
        }
        });
       
    </script>
```

Comment: What is your use case for not refreshing the entire page? It's simple and intuitive.

Comment: @MayurEkbote I think he's looking for a way to preserve any form data or state in the application, and simply reconnect.